# Display debuggers not showing up in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, debuggervisualizer

I've been working on a display debugger for Visual Studio 2017, and everything builds fine, but it doesn't show up in the list of display debuggers for the type.  I've tried debugging in a temp instance of VS and installing the VSIX manually.  I've checked a few projects I've found online, and everything seems identical.  What could cause this?  My fear is it's a change with 2017 that isn't documented (the VS SDK Github project doesn't have display debugger samples, and the VS templates don't reference it either).

My project is a class library, .NET 4.6.1, Any CPU, Debug or Release

The simplest example still doesn't work, but here it is:

```
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(Test.TestVisualizer), typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
    Target = typeof(System.String), Description = "Test Viz")]
namespace Test
{
    public class TestVisualizer : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        override protected void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            var str = objectProvider.GetObject()?.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show($"Value: {str}", "Visualizer");
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I modified the project file to just save the output files in addition to the VSIX.  It turns out, the VSIX didn't actually contain the DLL.  When I copied the DLL files to the Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Visualizers folder it works.  I guess I just need to figure out VSIX packaging!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if this issue has been resolved, not post the solution in your issue, just post it as the answer, and then mark it as the answer. So it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)

Comment: Sure.  That problem is solved, but it still doesn't actually work.  If I drag the DLL to the Visualizers folder, it works.  Even though the VSIX contains the DLL, it still doesn't work from the VSIX even when ProvideAutoLoad is set to UIContextGuids80.Debugging (and though the package does activate).  I can close the question, but it's not really resolved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the extension itself is fine.  The issue is with VSIX packaging or activation of the actual visualizer.  I'll create a new question for that.

[EDIT] It turns out that VSIX package installing **cannot** be used for managed debugger visualizers.  No errors, but it simply will not work.  The **only** way to install a managed debugger visualizer is to copy the files to your Visualizers folder (reference in original question).  You can do this manually or with an MSI.  This needs to be documented!

Comment: You could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue.